# Playing HLS on Chromecast with Wowza as the media server

Tags: ios, wowza, chromecast

I finally got HLS video playing working by using these codes from googlecast github repo:

- receiver=> github.com/googlecast/cast-custom-receiver
- media server=> github.com/googlecast/cast-support-media-server
- ios sender=> github.com/googlecast/CastHelloVideo-ios

The HLS playing works well with the HLS media google team provides=> http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/cast-media-server-samples%2Fmedia.zip

But I got error while trying to play out production HLS from Wowza.
The test stream from cast-support-media-server and my productuion HLS both are played well with ffplay though.
Here is error message I got:

http://pastebin.com/7aXbC6Hn

Did I miss something here ???